# The Money Force

Tags: ethics

> Should money be classified as a force.
>
> this was just a test to see if anyone who votes down a subject actually reads it. It was not correct but no one noticed why. No one mentioned the Galatic laws?
>   There is no such thing. Please before you vote something down actually read it.

we should vote down these votes

`According to Newton, a force must have its opponent. So, in this case, we have positive and debt. So indeed it is a good Force. According to the galactic laws, a force must also contain within itself the opposite. We got that. Within Galactic laws of force, it also must not slow down or speed up to be considered a force. I think we can get by on that one I mean money doesn't have a speed so we can say it's a constant.
So by definition, if money is a force. Does Consciousness control it or does it control consciousness?`According to Newton, a force must have its opponent. So, in this case, we have positive and debt. So indeed it is a good Force. According to the galactic laws, a force must also contain within itself the opposite. We got that. Within Galactic laws of force, it also must not slow down or speed up to be considered a force. I think we can get by on that one I mean money doesn't have a speed so we can say it's a constant.
So by definition, if money is a force. Does Consciousness control it or does it control consciousness?

Answer (score 1):

No. Money is a medium of exchange.

Comment: thats more of force then. A force equal forces exchange.

Comment: it controls everything in our world. if one treats it as a force you could calculate the effects of this force.

Comment: @internet-entity If you had asked on an economics forum, you would have gotten better answers perhaps.

Comment: gordon thank you very much, i did not know there was economics forum. certainly would do better there

Comment: well i cant delete it wont let me so i guess its forever now